# Cannot get terminal command to work with subprocess

Tags: python, cmd, terminal, subprocess, kivy

I have been trying for some time to execute a certain command in order to activate a test script. This test script will be activated when pressing a button of a kivy written GUI. That part is irrelevant, the basis of the question is that I am having difficulty writing this command to the terminal and thus executing the specified test script.

I have an understand of how to use subprocess, I have used it many time before without issue however in this scenario its proving to be rather *Annoying* shall we say.

Here is my attempt:

```
print subprocess.call(['cordova-test','android','tests','--app','platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk','--device-name=emulator-5554','--no-compile'],
   cwd = '/Users/User/Documents/dev/engineerappcopy')
```

Sorry it is rather lengthy and difficult to read, so when I click the button this is attached to it returns '127' which I know correlates to the computer not recognizing the specified path name. Well the thing is, is that the path name is correct I can type this into the terminal when in the correct directory which I have specified in the cwd call. So... the root of the question.. what am I doing wrong here? Many thanks to any help whats so ever.

Answer (score 0):

The equal to operator may be causing trouble. Can you try subprocess query with`shell=True`

`subprocess.call("query",shell=True,cwd="path")`